# Moderator election

Tags: discussion, moderation

I was under the impression that with graduation came the election of moderators, since the current moderating team has been nominated by SE. Does anybody know the exact process?

Comment: They usually wait a week or two after graduation, I'd just ask someone from the comm team in TL if you want to know more.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

About a month after graduation, elections take place. They'll initally start with three positions. All current (pro-tempore) mods will need to run for re-election at that point.

(Source: [this discussion in TL](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/15235642#15235642), only accessible to moderators)

Comment: Well, current mods will need to run for reelection only if they want to keep their positions. ;-)